# Removes spaces from a string

Tags: python, string

I can't, and I can't figure out what's wrong. The lists I'm trying to strip of spaces are like this:

```
['L500', '    ', '622651    ', '2007', '   452295.00', '        7420', '   0']
```

but with spaces inbetween. I've tried `lstrip`, `rstrip`, `regex`, `split`, `join`, `replace`, and nothing works. The list doesn't change.

```
for item in row:
            item.lstrip()
            item.rstrip()
            print row
```

That's my code. Replace lstrip, rstrip with the other methods I mentioned.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: And what is the language that you're using? Tell us.

Comment: a) what language and b) do you want to strip spaces from the entries, like ' L500' should become 'L500' or do you want to remove empty Strings from the array/list?

Comment: Is it intended that your examples do not contain spaces?

Comment: Sorry I'm using Python.

Comment: I want to remove all spaces, but the empty strings will stay put.

Comment: The spaces were erased when I submitted.

Comment: `lstrip()` returns a new string and does not modify the current one.

Answer (score 7):

Strings in python (and many other languages) are immutable. That means that when you do operations on a string, you get back a new instance of that string, instead of changing existing items. To do what you want, you have to reasign the items in the list.

```
for index, item in enumerate(row):
    row[index] = item.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Sorry I forgot about that strings are immutable. I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension:

```
row = [x.strip() for x in row]
```

Comment: If you don't want do rebind the variable you can use: `row[:] = [x.strip() for x in row]`.

Comment: "In python 3 that will, however, return generator."  No, it won't.  It'll return a list.

Answer (score 3):

Just another way:

```
>>> row = map(lambda x: x.strip(), row)
```

Comment: `row = map(str.strip, row)` is much faster